# Ruby on Rails form skip https validation for wss url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this simple form in Ruby on Rails that is for a Camera registration. It asks for the name, IP URL and WSS URL. My problem is that for my second url (wss) is also asking to be a valid URL (in the form of https) which is wrong. How can I disable or skip https validation for this input?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@camera, validate: false, html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= display_base_errors @camera %>

  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Camera name' %>
  <%= f.input :ip, label: 'IP / URL' %>
  <%= f.input :wss_url, label: 'WSS URL' %>

  <%= render 'shared/partials/botones_form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

and here is the wrong validation: the red tooltip means 'This value should be a valid url.'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the documentation

https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type

you can use the :as-Parameter to define this field not being an URL

Another option would be to rename the column to no include "url"

Comment: The as: parameter did the trick. Thank you!